# How to pass a url variable into an Ajax post script to preload a form input in search field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage that has a dynamic search field that will query a database as you type in the search string (much like a google search with suggestions as you type).  This part works via AJAX.

In the results, there are multiple rows of data that are displayed below as data is entered into the search field.  What I decided to do is create an edit link on the right side of each row (with pencil icon) that is returned by ajax so I can click to another page for editing the data.  Something like this...

```
<a href="edit.php?id=12&search=Goodyear"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-
hidden="true"></i></a>
```

So lets say that I searched for "Goodyear" in the example search and on row 12, I click the link that takes me to another page.  I was wanting to use $_GET["search"] to turn around and create a BACK link to the original AJAX page. I know how to get this far, however, I need help customizing the ajax to reload the original search (which in this example is "Goodyear") when the link is clicked back to the search page.  The link on the EDIT page would look something like:

```
 <a href="search.php?search=Goodyear">Back to Search Page</a>
```

But here is the issue.  When the user returns, I need the search bar prefilled and the search results listed below.  In other words, I want the page to be just like it was when they left prior to going to the edit page.  I want AJAX to search the search again on page load just because it visited this url /search.php?search=Goodyear  Making the url in the link on the edit page is not a problem for me.  But it is when it is clicked to return to original search page.

Here is the AJAX code that does all the heavy lifting on the search.php page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        load_data();

        function load_data(query) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { query: query },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#brand').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#search_text').keyup(function () {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if (search != '') {
                load_data(search);
            }
            else {
                load_data();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know that this search happens on a keyup event and the div called #brand displays the resulting rows of data below the search bar.  It actually works well just on the search alone, but leaving the page and clicking back with a url (search.php?search="goodyear") like I mentioned is not doing what I need it to. 
 When I try to modify it, the search results stop showing. .

I have tried to customize this code to process the url using GET variable within this code that uses POST in the AJAX but I have been been unsuccessful so far.  Any ideas on what I need to do?

I found the original page I originally used to make my search page.. here it if anyone wants to look: http://www.webslesson.info/2016/03/ajax-live-data-search-using-jquery-php-mysql.html

Comment: Modify the load_data function or create a new similar function and call it in page load if a GET variable is present

Comment: Thanks Waleed Iqbal! That formatting does look better!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect answer but it does work pretty nicely.  Although the only thing it does not do is show the text in the search field when you return to the page.  If anyone know how, give the answer... but this is what I did...

I found a nice piece of code that strips out the value of the parameter in the url and then throws it into an array variable. I found it on http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/8-useful-jquery-snippets-for-urls-querystrings/.  Here is the code.

```
var vars = [], hash;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[1]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
 }

load_data(vars['search']);
```

search is the parameter in the url and if it says search.php?search=255 then it returns 255.  So I threw that into the load_data argument value and it does the search.  The only drawback so far is I haven't figured out how to make the value show in the search bar.  I'll keep plugging.

UPDATE:  I figured out the text in search box issue with this code:

```
$('input[name="search_text"]').val(vars['search']);
```

It put the search parameter back into the search input field like I wanted!  One more note, be sure to put the above code above the load_data(vars['search']);  may not matter but that is what I did to make it work!

This is what it looked like:

```
var vars = [], hash;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[1]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
 }
$('input[name="search_text"]').val(vars['search']);
load_data(vars['search']);
```